# How to iterate over webelement

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi i have this code which takes text from this element
but because its web element i cant append it to list or loop over it how i can do this.

here is my code

```
import selenium
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
import contextlib as textmanager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
PATH= "C:\chromedrivers\chromedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)



driver.get("https://typetest.io/")



textt= driver.find_element_by_class_name("test-word")

for items in textt:
    print(items.text)
```

here is the output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ramhelsinki\projects\selenium typtest.io .py", line 26, in <module>
    for items in textt:
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `elements` instead of `element` like this -

```
textt = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("test-word")
```